# Auto lay-out swift doesn't work properly on labels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

i'm having trouble using auto lay-out in swift. I made a scroll view and added equal widths and heights, and centered it in y and x to the view. I added the following constraint in the code: `ScrollView.contentsize.heigt = 1300`

I added some labels, as you can see in this [image: picture], this hasn't got any auto lay-out so far.

When i do "add missing constraints", this happens: [image: with auto lay-out]

Now all my labels want to be way wider than they should be and than they are in the picture above. Does anyone know how i could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: add missing constraints for this  UI ...  always creates problem ... add constraint manually as per your need

Comment: Auto-layout for scrollview is never an easy task for beginner. You can find some topics/video that guides for this. And as @EICaptainv2.0 said, you should not use "add missing constraints". It just makes your view more complex and mess.

Answer (score 1):

try This steps it will help you

Step 1: Take View hierarchy like display in Image

[image]

Step 2: Give Top, Left, Right, Bottom constrains to scrollview with it's superview

[image]

Step 3: Give Top, Left, Right, Bottom and Hight constrains to container view with it's scrollView

[image]

Step 4: Align Center Horizontally constrains to container view with it's scrollView

[image]

After it you can define the individual label constrains to your label as per your requirement